# Wo[hin] soll ich mich setzen?

Tags: word-usage, reflexive

If I got it right, while *wo* is being used normally for questions about a position of a state, *wohin* is being used normally for questions about a final position of a movement.

Various clear examples include:

> Wo liegt das Buch? / Wohin soll ich das Buch legen?
>
> Wo stehen die Blumen? / Wohin sollen wir die Blumen stellen?
>
> Wo sitzt Hans? / Wohin soll ich das Baby setzen?

(I am not completely sure about the last example)

However, at least in some of the cases of reflexive verbs, I couldn't find a clear pattern. I usually distinguish *ich sitze* from *ich setze mich* as thinking of the latter as an action I am doing on myself (just like doing it "on" Hans, the baby). So I would expect the following:

> Wohin soll ich mich setzen?

But I do see a lot of these:

> Wo soll ich mich setzen?

In [this page](https://www.facebook.com/dw.learngerman/posts/10152162679307394?comment_id=32555629&offset=0&total_comments=37) I even saw both forms in the same "conversation", so I'm quite confused. I can just guess that both forms are alright, but if that's the case, is it only with *setzen*? Is it with reflexive verbs in general?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example "Wohin soll ich das Baby setzen" is fine.

> "Wo soll ich mich setzen?"

is a bit odd, usually you say

> "Wo soll ich mich HINsetzen?"

This contains your wohin - but it is split up. The "hin" is moved to the verb.

I think you can say "Wohin" is used when the verb expresses some kind of movement while "Wo" is used to ask for the current location.

Comment: you are right, I would say "Wo soll ich mich setzen" even if being odd is often used in spoken German, because people are lazy

Comment: yes, but it is (accepted) incorrect/elliptic. Another example is "dann setzen wir uns" - would also be "dann setzen wir uns hin", but the first is much more common..

Answer (score 2):

That's how I'd order it. The ones from your list in bold.

Wo darf ich mich setzen? very formal

Wohin darf ich mich setzen? formal

**Wohin soll ich mich setzen?** less formal

**Wo soll ich mich setzen?** even less formal would not use that one personally

Wo soll ich mich hinsetzen? informal

Und wo soll ich mich hinsetzen? very informal

Answer (score 2):

**Wo** and **Wohin** can also be used to emphasize when repeating a question. Consider the following dialogue.

> Me   : Wo soll ich mich setzen?
>
> Host : Dahinten
>
> Me   : Wohin soll ich mich setzen?
>
> Host : Dahinten neben meiner Schwägerin.

Answer (score 1):

Da sowohl

> Ich setze mich auf den Stuhl am Tischende.

(wohin?) als auch

> Ich setze mich am Tischende.

(wo?) korrekte und sinnvolle Sätze sind, gilt dies auch für beide Fragen.

In der Tat würde ich, wenn ich förmlich sein möchte, „Wo darf ich mich setzen?“ vorziehen, auch wenn ich mir nicht sicher bin, warum. Das mag daran liegen, dass *hinsetzen* unnötig erscheint, und vielleicht auch an der Unsicherheit bezüglich *wo hinsetzen* and *wohin setzen*, which may have been discussed elsewhere here.

Comment: "Ich setze mich am Tischende." klingt sowas von falsch für mich. Dein erstes Beispiel würde komisch klingen wenn man es ergänzt, aber es ist der Fall des elliptischen-"hin"..

Comment: Ich bin am Tischende, und dort setze ich mich.

Comment: HIN! ;) natürlich weiß ich, was gemeint ist, aber ich habe es so noch nie gehört oder würde es sagen.. Kann aber lokal sein..?

Comment: Kommt Dir die Aufforderung „Setzen Sie sich!“ auch komisch vor?

Comment: Nein, Dir "Hinsetzen" oder "Setzen Sie sich (wieder) hin!" ? Ich denke bei dem Tischende liegt es an der Präposition.. Wie gesagt, eventuell lokale Unterschiede..

Comment: Ich benutze auch eher *hinsetzen*, ziehe aber das einfachere *sich setzen* vor, wenn ich auf meine Sprache achte.